# I need to find the function of this graph in factored form (if possible with solution)

Tags: rational-functions

[image]

Copy and paste the lik above for pic.

I already know that the function is (?)/(x+2)(x-1)
Horizontal Asymptote is y=0
i don't know how to get both intercepts in this since the possible y intercept is the hole (0,2)

Comment: He asked at Stack Exchange.

Comment: im stuck at getting the denominator's factorrs.

Comment: Don't put it in comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: There is an "edit"-button on the bottom of the question itself, right above where the comments start. You can click that and edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a vertical asymptote at $x = -2$, which means that there is a factor of $x+2$ in the denominator. In addition, along this asymptote, the graph on the left and right sides go the same direction, so it should have an even power.

There is a vertical asymptote at $x = 1$, which means there is a factor of $x-1$. Here the graph goes in both directions, so the power is odd. It is also narrower than the $-2$ asymptote, so the power is probably lower.

Finally, there is a zero at $x = 2$, which means $x-2$ is a factor of the denominator.

Putting this together, the simplest function we can make is
$$
\frac{x-2}{(x+2)^2(x-1)}
$$
which does indeed look a lot like your function. However, we need to do something about the undefined point at $x = 0$. That's remedied by multiplying numerator and denominator by $x$, like so:
$$
\frac{x(x-2)}{x(x+2)^2(x-1)}
$$

---

**Edit:** The odd and even power.

For a term like $x-1$, if we're just a little to the left of $1$, then it's negative, while if we're a little to the right, it's positive. The same goes for $1/(x-1)$, although instead of having values close to $0$, they're blown up toward their respective infinities.

In other words, a linear factor, either in the numerator or the denominator, *changes sign* as you pass through where it's $0$, and as such, changes the sign of the entire function.

However, if that factor is squared instead, then it doesn't change sign. For instance, $(x+2)^2$ (or, more relevant to our question, $1/(x+2)^2$) is positive both to the left and to the right of $x = -2$. There are several ways to explain this, the most common is probably to say that squares are never negative. I'm partial to explaining it as the sign changing *twice* as you pass $x = -2$. What I mean by that is $(x+2)^2 = (x+2)(x+2)$, and as you pass through $x = -2$, both of those factors change sign (as per the paragraph above), so we get a double sign change, which is the same as no sign change.

From this we see that a cubed factor changes sign, while a factor to the fourth power doesn't, and so on.

Comment: thanks but can you explain in simple terms the odd and even power?

Comment: @LloydCarganilla I added a brief explanation to my answer.